# Tradingview - Label only the Highest High in the last days

Tags: tradingview-api

```
`//@version=5
indicator(title='Label', overlay=true)

ma_length = input.int(1, title="Length", group="Settings")
tf = input.string("Day", title="Timeframe", options=['Chart', 'Minute', 'Hour', 'Day', 'Week'], group="Settings")

//LookBack = input.int(defval = 3)
LookBack=7
highestHigh = ta.highest(high, LookBack)

lowestLows = ta.lowest(low, LookBack)


f_remove_labels(lbl_arr, lb) =>
    temp_arr = array.new_label()
    len = array.size(lbl_arr)

    if (len > 0)
        for i=0 to len-1
            lbl = array.get(lbl_arr, i)
            idx = label.get_x(lbl)
            
            
            if ((bar_index - idx) >= lb)
                label.delete(lbl)
            else
                array.push(temp_arr, lbl)
    temp_arr

var high_labels = array.new_label()



lbl2 = label.new(bar_index, na, "3Day High:" + str.tostring(highestHigh), color=color.rgb(223, 68, 68), textcolor=color.rgb(226, 229, 237), style=label.style_none, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
array.push(high_labels, lbl2)

label_1=f_remove_labels(high_labels, LookBack)

f_remove_lower_labels(lbl_to_shorten) =>
    max_arr = array.new_float()
    len_temp_arr = array.size(lbl_to_shorten)

    if (len_temp_arr > 0)

        for j=0 to len_temp_arr - 1
            lbl_value = array.get(lbl_to_shorten, j)
            next_lbl_value = array.get(lbl_to_shorten, j+1)
            idx_label_value = label.get_x(lbl_value)
           
            if (lbl_value > next_lbl_value) //change the lbl_value type to simple float
                array.push(max_arr, lbl_value)
    max_arr
               

f_remove_lower_labels(label_1)



plot(high)
plot(highestHigh)
```

Function "f_remove_labels" works great with shortening the big array of labels to only how far i want it to look. Now, it displays the label on all days instead of just one day that i want it to display on. The day should have the highest high of all the values that exist in that label array.

Hence i started making the other function "f_remove_lower_labels" to remove all those values that are smaller than the biggest value. I think i am messing it up at if condition " if (lbl_value > next_lbl_value) " due to not comparing the right kind of data.